# Restar el valor anterior de una misma columna al siguiente elemento

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una columna de valores:

```
valores
15 
23 
54 
32 
53
```

Lo que quiero conseguir, es restarle a cada numero el valor anterior y crear con eso otra elemento con la columna con las soluciones. Ademas, dado que el primero no tiene un valor anterior, me gustaría darle el valor de la resta de la segunda fila.

Comment: Bienvenido Usune a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que tengas un data frame, esta es la forma de hacerlo

```
df <- data.frame(valores = c(15, 23, 54, 32, 53))

df <- df %>%
        mutate(diferencia = valores - lag(valores, 1))

df$diferencia[1] <- df$diferencia[2]
```

Si lo que tienes es un vector, entonces como sigue:

```
valores <- c(15, 23, 54, 32, 53)    
diferencia <- diff(valores)
diferencia <- c(diferencia[2], diferencia)
```

Espero esto te ayude.